# Tkinter save model with combination of pickle and filedialog

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to save a model with a combination of pickle & filedialog but the model is not saved in sav format but in a file format which opens improperly. That is my code:

```
    filename = str (element_u) + "_" + str ((",".join (pls_crop))) + "_" + str (whichButton) # File name extract according to user selected of elment & crop
    export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename (initialdir=os.getcwd (),initialfile=filename,defaultextension='.pkl')
    pickle.dump (model_RF, open (filename, 'wb'))
```

Comment: It's hard to help you with what you put in the question. What does "improperly opens" mean? The problem surely does not come from tkinter. I don't know anything about the file format .sav but are you sure that `model_RF` is a proper model and that using `pickle` is the proper approach to save it? If you are using a library to handle these models, maybe it has a method to save them properly or some documentation.

Comment: when I save the model without filedialog, but only with pickle the saving complete. when I trying to combine both pickle and both filedialog, the format of the file change

Comment: What filename do you give when you don't use filedialog? And what is the filename you get when you try to use the filedialog? Because filedialog just returns a filename so it doesn't influence the pickling part. The only thing that can happen is that the pickled data does not have the extension you expected but it does not change the format of the data in the file, it just prevents softwares to detect that the file has the correct format.

Comment: The `export_file_path` is not used at all, so the use of filedialog is useless.